# Tikzing a circled star

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have used

```
\tikzcircle[fill=red]{3pt} This item.
```

for showing a filled circle for an item. But I wish to have a circled star as below one instead of single circle. How can I use Ti*k*Z for constructing that?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can always build your own.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{mystar/.cd, 
color/.initial=red,
fill/.initial=blue!20,
style/.code={\tikzset{mystar style/.style={#1}}},
style={}}
\newcommand{\mystar}[1][]{\tikz{
\tikzset{mystar/.cd,#1}
\node [star, star point height=.15em, minimum size=.4em,
inner sep=0.1em, draw=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mystar/color},
fill=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mystar/fill},line width=0.05em,mystar style]
        {};
        \draw[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mystar/color},
        line width=0.05em] circle[radius=.35em];}}
\begin{document}
ABC \mystar\ DEF

{\Huge ABC \mystar[color=orange]\mystar[style={rotate=36}]\ DEF}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

One can draw it quite easily with `intersections`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\radius{2};
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {90,18,...,-288} {
    \coordinate (\j) at (\i:\radius);
}
\path[name path=13] (1)--(3);
\path[name path=35] (3)--(5);
\path[name path=52] (5)--(2);
\path[name path=24] (2)--(4);
\path[name path=41] (4)--(1);
\path[name intersections={of=13 and 52,by=x1}];
\path[name intersections={of=13 and 24,by=x2}];
\path[name intersections={of=35 and 24,by=x3}];
\path[name intersections={of=35 and 41,by=x4}];
\path[name intersections={of=52 and 41,by=x5}];
\draw[very thick,red,fill=blue!50,rounded corners=1pt] (1)--(x1)--(2)--(x2)--(3)--(x3)--(4)--(x4)--(5)--(x5)--cycle;
\draw[very thick, red] (0,0) circle[radius=\radius];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course, with some maths, the code will be shorter, but this way is straight-forward.

[image]

#### Edit:

I just see that you will use the star as a "bullet" in `itemize`. We can define a new command for this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\newcommand{\tikzstar}{\tikz{
    \def\radius{.3em};
    \foreach \i [count=\j] in {90,18,...,-288} {
        \coordinate (\j) at (\i:\radius);
    }
    \path[name path=13] (1)--(3);
    \path[name path=35] (3)--(5);
    \path[name path=52] (5)--(2);
    \path[name path=24] (2)--(4);
    \path[name path=41] (4)--(1);
    \path[name intersections={of=13 and 52,by=x1}];
    \path[name intersections={of=13 and 24,by=x2}];
    \path[name intersections={of=35 and 24,by=x3}];
    \path[name intersections={of=35 and 41,by=x4}];
    \path[name intersections={of=52 and 41,by=x5}];
    \draw[very thin,red,fill=blue!50] (1)--(x1)--(2)--(x2)--(3)--(x3)--(4)--(x4)--(5)--(x5)--cycle;
    \draw[very thin,red] (0,0) circle[radius=\radius];
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \renewcommand\labelitemi{\tikzstar}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
\end{itemize}
\begin{huge}
\begin{itemize}
    \renewcommand\labelitemi{\tikzstar}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
\end{itemize}
\end{huge}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Just for fun – a very short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}

\usepackage{pst-poly}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

 \begin{postscript}
\psset{linecolor=Tomato, linewidth=0.4pt}
A CIRCLED \makebox[1em]{\pscirclebox[framesep=-1.4pt]{\PstStarFive[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=CornflowerBlue, linejoin=1, unit =0.115]}} STAR
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Without TikZ, with `mnsymbol` and `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mnsymbol}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\mycircledstar}{%
    \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{%
        \textcolor{red}{$\bigcircle$}%
        }{%
        \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{%
            \textcolor{red}{\scalebox{0.65}{$\largestar$}}%
            }{%
            \textcolor{cyan}{\scalebox{0.6}{$\bigstar$}}%
            }%
        }
    }
\begin{document}
    Little \mycircledstar and big \scalebox{10}{\mycircledstar}
\end{document}
```

[image]